# TypeError: a.dot(...).equals is not a function

Tags: javascript, class, methods, prototype, typeerror

In the below code, there are 3 methods: add, dot and equals. The add and dot methods calculate  the addition and dot product of two vectors. The equals method checks that the return values of the add and dot methods match the argument passed to the equals method.

I'm getting the error `TypeError: a.dot(...).equals is not a function` if I try to invoke the equals method on the dot method. What am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work? There are no errors when I invoke the equals method on the add method.

```
function Vector(vector){

      this.vector=vector;
      }

      //add method
      Vector.prototype.add= function(b){
        var res=[];
        var vec1 =this["vector"];
        var vec2 = b["vector"];
        for (i=0; i<vec1.length; i++){
          res.push(vec1[i]+vec2[i]);
        }
        var result = new Vector(res);
        return result;
      };
      //dot product method
      Vector.prototype.dot= function(b){
        var res=0;
        var vec1 =this["vector"];
        var vec2 = b["vector"];
        for (i=0; i<vec1.length; i++){
          res+=vec1[i]*vec2[i];
        }
        return res;
      };
      //equals method
      Vector.prototype.equals = function(answer){
        if (this.toString()===answer.toString()){
          return true;
        } else {
        console.log(this);
            return false;
        }
      };
    //test
    var a = new Vector([1,2]);
    var b = new Vector([3,4]);
    a.add(b).equals(new Vector([4,6]));
    a.dot(b).equals(11);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dot` method returns a `Number`, not a `Vector`.  Try using `==` instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Galluzzo is correct, but I thought I'd give more explanation, since I'm aware of the background (for the interested reader, this comes from a *Codewars* exercise: http://www.codewars.com/kata/vector-class/train/javascript).

The way you have written the method means that `a.dot(b).equals(11)` will compare the string representation of a `Vector` object with the string representation of `11`. These will clearly not be equal, since you will be comparing something like `'function Vector(vector) {...}'=='11'`.

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the `equals` method. It is the specific implementation of an equality check between objects of the `Vector` class *only*. When comparing built-in types you should use `==` or `===` if possible.

The description in the kata linked above says "The test cases will utilize the user-provided equals method", but the author means this *only* when making comparisons between `Vector` objects. When comparing the result of the `dot` or `norm` methods, the equality operators are used.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) for more about comparing objects. It also gives you some idea of why comparing the string representation of a whole object is not always a great idea.

Comment: I didn't realise the equals method should only be used for add and subtract. Thank you both